# Painting a Train Model

Tags: texture-painting, vertex-paint

I work for a model train company, and I've been doing the renders of upcoming products for our print and video advertising. I'm just getting my feet wet with Blender, but I've learned a fair amount over the past several months.

So far, I've been generating these plain renders without any artwork, just changing minor things like making the windows transparent and the wheels metallic. I'm fairly happy with how they look, but I want to take my game up a notch and "paint" them with the colours and logos that will be on the production models (see attached).

I've messed around with texture and vertex painting, both of which are convoluted messes for something that seems as though it should be relatively simple. For example, I'll paint the faces at the rear of the engine red like in the artwork, but then I'll also get random red blotches throughout the rest of the model.

Is there a straightforward manner in which to do this that I might be overlooking? For reference, I'm using STP files from our factory (imported with the STEPper plugin) and I'm on Blender 2.93.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Original render and desired artwork]

---

Postscript: Your answer was profoundly helpful and I can't thank you enough. While it was a bit tedious, particularly the gaskets around the windows, it was fairly straightforward and the painting is mostly done. I'll tackle the logos and stripes next. Thanks again!
[image]

Comment: hello you need to make sure that the unwrap is correct, also increase a bit the margin when you unwrap

Comment: Your tutorial was profoundly helpful and I can't thank you enough. While it was a bit tedious, particularly the gaskets around the windows, it was fairly straightforward and the painting is mostly done. I'll tackle the logos and stripes next. Thanks again!
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsiKi.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsiKi.jpg)

Comment: If you're glad with vklidu's answer you need to mark it as correct   ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, could be probably easier to assign material to specific object ... or if your train is single object, than assign materials to a specific faces. Like in this sample ...

[image]

For selected object add several Material slots. Add (or choose already created) material to each slot.

[image]

Red and Black parts of train are just Principle BSDF shader.
In edit mode select faces you want red and under Material Properties click Assign. Do it for each part of train.

For middle part of train I created material named "Strips" with this node tree, so you can adjust strip thickness, angle, scale, or height of top horizontal black part ...

[image]
[image]

Graphics (numbers or logo) can be placed as regular object or as an image texture.

Texture can be projected with some another object coordinates. Like *Empty* object ... here logo (black&white) used as Factor for MixRGB node.

[image]

[image]
[image]

... or you can position image texture by UV coordinates. For that you would have to Unwrap specific faces ...

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]